# Getting all Pages user is Admin of using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of all the pages the logged user an Admin of, but I am getting the error "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user". Here is the code I am using:

```
function login(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {

            $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts", function(data) {
                alert( "success" );
            })
            .done(function() {
                alert( "second success" );
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                alert( "error" );
            })
            .always(function() {
                alert( "finished" );
            });

        } else {
            // not auth / cancelled the login!
        }
    }, { scope: "manage_pages" });
}
```

So in this code, after logging in, the call $.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts") throws the error.

**UPDATE:**

I am able to get the the list using FB.api("/me/accounts"). So how come I can't get it using this code? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: which language is used ?

Comment: This is JavaScript, and an update, I am able to get the the list using FB.api("/me/accounts"). So how come I can't get it using this code? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: do you know about graph explorer in facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: You are not passing a user access token with your direct request:

```
$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts", function(data) { ... });
```

instead of

```
var accessToken = "aoidhfgoafhgoidfhg"; // replace with real access token
$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=" + accessToken, function(data) { ... });
```

The FB SDK does this internally/automatically. What's not really clear to me is why you don't use the FB SDK here as well, if you're already using it for FB Login. That doesn't make much sense IMHO.